# MFC, Ribbons - CMFCRibbonButton with image: Always show the text

Tags: mfc, ribbon-control

I've got an CMFCRibbonButton that displays a text and an icon. When I compact the ribbon, in the end only the small icon is shown.
Is there a way to tell the button not to get compacted into small icon state, but always show the text as well?
I tried pButton->SetCompactMode(FALSE); without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure, `CMFCRibbonButton::SetAlwaysLargeImage()` is not what you are looking for? I ask, because when only an icon without text is displayed, it is usually the panel the button sits in that has collapsed. See `CMFCRibbonPanel::IsCollapsed()`. If you want to modify the behavior of the panel so that it won't collape, you could try to subclass `CMFCRibbonPanel` and play with overrides. The MFC Ribbon is not completely documented but my best bet is `CMFCRibbonPanel::IsFixedSize()`:

```
class CMyPanel : public CMFCRibbonPanel
{
    ...
    BOOL IsFixedSize() const { return TRUE; }
    ...
}
```

If this doesn't work you have to see yourself what happens in `NotifyControlCommand` or `OnUpdateCmdUI` when the panel collapses and modify the behavior as needed.

Comment: I see now. I had buttons with tiny icons and did not want them to go into iconic state, but always display the text. I can do this by not setting an icon to these buttons.
SetAlwaysLargeImage() is OK for me. Many thanks.